# use variable for jquery css property name

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have seen plenty of threads asking how to use a variable for jquery's css method like

```
var black='#000000';
$(this).css({'color':black});
```

but none of how to use variables the other way round like

```
var bg='background-color';
$(this).css({bg:'#000000'});
```

For me it doesn't work like that, so I am asking, is there a way to make something like that work, to save some space when using 'background-color' a bunch of times in a script?

Thanks!

Comment: How about `var obj={}; obj[bg]=black; $(this).css(obj)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if it's a single property you could write in this way

```
var bg = 'background-color';
$(this).css(bg, '#000000');
```

if you need to pass an object you could define the `background-color` key as a variable inside squared brackets

```
var bg = 'background-color';

var obj = {};
obj[bg] = '#000000';
$(this).css(obj);
```

Comment: OP wants to pass `object` as argument...You can not set many styles using syntax provided by you..

Comment: @RayonDabre I don't see this as a strict requirement for the OP: _“is there a way to make something like that“_ - anyway I've edited and show both the ways

Comment: This obj method just saved my bacon, it's a really nice method.

Answer (score 2):

Use `bracket` notation to use variable as `key` of the object

```js
var obj = {};
var bg = 'background-color';
var black = '#000000';
obj[bg] = black;
$('div').css(obj)
```

```css
div {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the version of [.css(propertyName, value)](http://var%20bg%20=%20'background-color';%20$(this).css(bg,%20'#000000');) that takes the style name and parameter

```js
$('div').each(function() {
  var bg = 'background-color';
  $(this).css(bg, '#000000');
})
```

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>some</div>
<div>test</div>
```